# how to change ODBC API in SSIS

Tags: ssis, odbc, ssis-2008

How to change ODBC API in SSIS 2008?

Seems that it is using ODBC 3.0 API and I want to change it to 2.5 API or below that.

Comment: But why you need this? You have driver for SSIS that supports only ODBC 2.5?

Comment: @Andrey : yes driver supports only 2.5 API.

Comment: and what the driver is? oracle?

Comment: @Andrey : it is a ISAM database driver

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your problem is and my answer is **not_a_really_answer**, but maybe it is better than nothing for you.

So, from [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313008)

> Microsoft does not provide a stand-alone installation package for the
>   ODBC components and drivers. ODBC can only be installed as part of the
>   Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)

well then in your case we are talking about `MDAC components`

As I know `MDAC` is a Windows component and therefore it cannot be easily removed or (re)installed. But despite of this:

- Try to explore [MDAC versions history](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231943) (maybe it is still possible to download some of them)
- [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313008) you can find list of MDAC components (DLLs - which theoretically may be replaced with older ones)
- [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1953) to `MDAC Utility: Component Checker` - maybe it will be useful
- and some general info about the topic [FAQ About Windows DAC/MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692877(v=vs.85).aspx)
- and... good luck with your fight :)